# Why my Python code works only for a particular input?

Tags: python

I am learning Python at the moment and need a bit of help with my coding.

I have to create a program that calculates the number of boxes needed for a certain amount of items.

This is the complete task description:

> Different sized boxes can store a specific number of items. There are
>   3 kinds of boxes:
>
> - Big - can store up to 5 items
> - Medium - can store up to 3 items
> - Small - can only store 1 item
>
> The a program should:
>
> 1. Get the user to enter an integer to represent a number of items, assuming that the user enters any integer greater than 5
> 2. Calculate the minimum number of full boxes needed to store the items. Only the full boxes are allowed to be packed
> 3. Display the numbers of big, medium and small boxes used
> 4. Display the total number of boxes

Here is my code:

```
if item >= 5 :
if item % 5 == 0 :
    big = int(item / 5)
elif item % 5 > 0 :
    big = int(item / 5)
    remitem = item % 5

    if remitem >= 3 :
        if remitem % 3 == 0 :
            med = int(remitem / 3)
        if remitem % 3 >= 1 :
            med = 0
        elif remitem % 3 > 2 :
            med = int(remitem / 3)
```

The problem is, that if I enter 18, it gives me the right number of boxes, but if I put 19, it does not.

How to fix this?

I am using Python 3.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

here is the simplest answer

```
def printBoxes(item):
    big  = int(item/5)
    remitem = item - big*5
    med = int(remitem/3)
    small = remitem - med*3
    print "big - %s \nmedium - %s \nsmall - %s" % (big, med, small)

printBoxes(99)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if item >= 5 : 
    if item % 5 == 0 : 
            big = int(item / 5) 
   elif item % 5 > 0 : 
           big = int(item / 5) 
           remitem = item % 5

if remitem >= 3 :
    if remitem % 3 == 0 : 
           med = int(remitem / 3)
    if remitem % 3 == 1 : 
         #modified this part of code
          med = int(remitem/3)
          small=1
    elif remitem % 3 ==2 : 
          small=remitem
```

Guess you missed the code for the 'small' box.

Comment: Yeah I hadnt even got that far!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just overcomplicated the problem which made coding it harder, the route using the modulu `%` and remainders, if you make the math simpler the coding becomes simpler too

```
num_items = int(input("Enter the number of items to store: "))
big = int(num_items/5)
med = int((num_items - big * 5)/ 3)
small = num_items - big * 5 - med * 3 
total = big + med + small

print(f"\nBig boxes: {big}\nMedium boxes: {med}\nSmall boxes: {small}")
print(f"\nTotal Boxes : {total}")
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 this.py
> Enter the number of items to store: 12
>
> Big boxes: 2
> Medium boxes: 0
> Small boxes: 2
>
> Total Boxes : 4
> ```

Comment: Oh my word! thank you so so much! this makes so much more sense!!

Comment: If this solved your problem click accept solution so other users don’t spend time on a resolved issue, cheers